# Reading and printing a text file in Java

Tags: java, file

I am trying to read lines from a text file in Java, but there is a lot going on. Is this the best way to do this? I am especially concerned with resource leaks.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Filing {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("/Users/thomaspovinelli/Desktop/apps.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String buffer;
        String fulltext="";
        while ((buffer = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(buffer);
            fulltext += buffer;
        }
        br.close();
        fr.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import java.io.*;
```

Never import the full package. It is considered bad practice to do so. Instead, import what you need and only what you need.

Instead of just reading a file then printing it, why don't you create a method that reads all line of a file and returns a list of all the lines? This way, you can do more with the result:

```
public static List<String> getAllLines(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String buffer;
    String fulltext="";
    while ((buffer = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(buffer);
        fulltext += buffer;
    }
    br.close();
    fr.close();
}
```

> I am especially concerned with resource leaks.

Since Java 7, there is such thing as a try-with-resources statement, which automatically closes the reader when an exception occurs, which you are not doing here. Your current code *has memory leaks*!

With some other improvements:

```
public static List<String> readAllLines(File file) {
    List<String> result = new LinkedList<>();
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        for (String current = reader.readLine(); current != null; current = reader
                .readLine()) {
            result.add(current);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

By the way, this is actually the code I use often to read all lines of a file.

Comment: It would be safer to construct `BufferedReader` and `FileReader` separately rather than as a chain, in case the `FileReader` constructor succeeds but the `BufferedReader` constructor fails.

Comment: If you want a `public static List<String> readAllLines(…)`, just use [`java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(file.toPath())`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-). And I don't see any reason to catch an exception that you don't really know how to handle at that point.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about the *best* way, but I'd personally favor one of the options using [java.nio](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) and [java.util.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

Option 1:

```
public static List<String> readAllLines(String fileName) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        result.addAll(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Option 2:

```
public static List<String> readAllLines(String fileName) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName))) {
        br.lines().forEachOrdered(result::add);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

And if for some reason you cannot use either of those, you might want to have a look at [`FileUtils#readLines(java.io.File)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines(java.io.File)) from [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) (although it's probably not worth adding that dependency *only* for this task).

In general, if you are concerned about (potential) resource leaks and you are using Eclipse, I advise to go to `Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings` and set the severity level of "Resource leak" and "Potential resource leak" to at least "Warning". This way your IDE will tell you where you need to be careful.

Comment: I think using `ArrayList` in lieu of `LinkedList` should be good enough. :)

Comment: @h.j.k.: True, changed it.

Answer (score 5):

`FileNotFoundException` is a kind of `IOException`, so you only need to declare `throws IOException`.

A cleaner way of ensuring that your resources get closed is to use try-with-resources.  Write it as `fr = …` and `br = …` instead of `br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(…))` to ensure that each resource gets closed, even if the `FileReader` constructor succeeds but the `BufferedReader` constructor fails.

```
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(…);
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
    StringBuilder fullText = new StringBuilder();
    for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; fullText.append(line)) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Repeated string concatenation (`fulltext += buffer`) is O(*n*<sup>2</sup>): each time you end up re-copying all of `fulltext` all over again.  Use a `StringBuilder` instead.  But in this program, you don't need to, since you never even use `fulltext`.  (By the way, your `fulltext` is probably not what you want: it has all of the line terminators stripped out, since that's what `BufferedReader.readLine()` does.)

There's nothing really line-oriented about your program, so there is little reason to scan for line breaks.  The simplest way to achieve the same results is using `java.nio.file.*`:

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(…), System.out);
```